# Ярлык приложения в Android

Tags: google-play, android

При установке приложений из Play Market в Android ярлыки автоматически создаются на главном экране, если там есть место.

Так вот такой вопрос: они создаются автоматически или это надо как-то в приложении программно задать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, это задается в манифесте приложения. Как правило, у приложений есть главное окно(Activity). Активность, в свою очередь, задается в манифесте приложения(AndroidManifest.xml). В манифесте же задаются параметры всех активностей приложения. Если вы когда-либо видели содержимое манифеста, то, возможно, замечали следующее:

```
<activity
     android:name=".StartPoint"
     android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Обратите внимание на вложенный конфиг-тег `intent-filter`, в котором указывается категория

> android.intent.category.LAUNCHER

Именно благодаря нему и появляются так называемые "ярлыки".

Comment: Да я знаю всё это, просто не знал, что именно благодаря этой строке появляется ярлык, теперь знаю, спасибо.